# Center points of PLSS sections

Tags: plss

Would it be possible to find lat-long pairs for the center point of every section or even quarter section in a state? The accuracy of the point as the center is irrelevant, I would just need any point within the section or quarter section.

Comment: What GIS software are you using? QGIS? ArcGIS? Something else? Pretty much every software package out there will have a function to generate polygon centroids. If you give us some more detail, it will be easy to suggest a solution.

Comment: I am not a GIS person, but I need this particular data. Therefore, I need to collect the high-level information that will allow me to seek out the resources I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a feature class of PLSS polygons in a Geographic Coordinate System then look for a tool within the GIS of your choice that can create a point within an output feature class at the centroid of those input polygons.

Comment: Thanks, based on this I was able to hire a freelancer to work on this and we are almost at a solution.